# How do you submit data from one worksheet to update a separate worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, stock

I am trying to develop a stock control system (on Microsoft Excel 2010) but I have encountered a problem, hopefully someone out there can help me with it!

I have a parts incoming worksheet and separate worksheets for each storage location. (5 of them)

On the parts incoming page you enter the parts name, quantity, a checkbox to say whether the invoice for the part has been added to the accountants file and a choice of where the part will be stored (i.e. the storage location) as a drop down selectable list.

**I want to create a submit button on the data entry sheet (parts incoming sheet) that will update the RELEVANT worksheet (the storage location selected by the user) and add the details submitted, to that worksheet. I know how to add the details (i think) but my question is how can you make it add the details to the selected storage location/worksheet?**

So far I have only really used macros and have a fairly limited knowledge on VBA but I am willing to try anything that you may think will let it work. I hope that makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks 
Toby

Comment: I can help you with exact directions if I can see a sample file :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, some simple examples of transferring cell values or ranges of cells from one sheet to another.

Create a commandButton on the worksheet, and attach this macro to it:

```
Sub TransferData() 
    Dim sht1 as Worksheet
    Dim sht2 as Worksheet

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parts Incoming")  '<-- modify as needed'
    Set sht2 = ThisWOrkbook.Sheets("Storage Location") '<-- modify as needed'

    'Example of placing cell value from B16 on Parts Incoming in the cell A1 on the storage location sheet.'
    sht2.Range("A1") = sht1.Range("B16") 

    'Example of transfering data from a Range of cells to another range of cells on a different worksheet:'
    sht2.Range("A1:A50") = sht1.Range("E50:E100")


    ' you will need to modify or add to this to transfer data from different places '

End Sub
```